# ¿Como agregar una fila en una tabla?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

Estoy mostrando una tabla correctamente, pero necesito que una vez se terminen de mostrar las filas del campo "sibasi" se genere una nueva fila en el cual se mostrara el total por mes.

Esta es la tabla que ya genero
[image: Esta es la tabla que ya genero]

Necesito lograr tener los totales como esta img, por ejemplo despues de que se muestre las dos filas de sibasi oriente se debe crear una nueva en la cual realizar el total.
[image]

Esta seria la conexion y consulta a la bd

```
// Configuración necesaria para acceder a la data base.
$hostname = "localhost";
$usuariodb = "root";
$passworddb = "";
$dbname = "estadistica";
    
// Generando la conexión con el servidor
$conectar = mysqli_connect($hostname, $usuariodb, $passworddb, $dbname);

//capturando el valor del id de la region 
$uno=$atencurativas['AtenCurativa']['regiones_id']; 

//Cosulta mysql
$sql = "SELECT sibasis.nombre, establecimientos.nombre_esta, atencurativasxesta.enero,atencurativasxesta.febrero, atencurativasxesta.marzo, atencurativasxesta.abril, atencurativasxesta.mayo, atencurativasxesta.junio, atencurativasxesta.julio, atencurativasxesta.agosto, atencurativasxesta.septiembre, atencurativasxesta.octubre, atencurativasxesta.noviembre, atencurativasxesta.diciembre FROM atencurativasxesta INNER JOIN establecimientos ON atencurativasxesta.establecimientos_id = establecimientos.id INNER JOIN sibasis ON establecimientos.sibasis_id = sibasis.id where sibasis.regiones_id=$uno ORDER BY sibasis.id";

$resultado = mysqli_query($conectar, $sql);
?>
```

los datos son traidos gracias a un while a la bd

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
<h1>Atencion Curativas</h1><br>

<p><?php echo $this->Html->link("Nueva Atencion Curativa", array('controller' => 'atencurativas', 'action' => 'add')); ?></p>
<table class="table">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th class="text-center">SIBASI</th>
      <th class="text-center">ESTABLECIMIENTO</th>
      <th class="text-center">ENERO</th>
      <th class="text-center">FENRERO</th>
      <th class="text-center">MARZO</th>
      <th class="text-center">ABRIL</th>
      <th class="text-center">MAYO</th>
      <th class="text-center">JUNIO</th>
      <th class="text-center">JULIO</th>
      <th class="text-center">AGOSTO</th>
      <th class="text-center">SEPTIEMBRE</th>
      <th class="text-center">OCTUBRE</th>
      <th class="text-center">NOVIEMBRE</th>
      <th class="text-center">DICIEMBRE</th>
      <th class="text-center">TOTAL ANUAL</th>


     
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) { ?>

    <tr>
      <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row["nombre"]; ?></td>
      <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row["nombre_esta"]; ?></td>
      <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row["enero"]; ?></td>
      <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row["febrero"]; ?></td>
      <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row["marzo"]; ?></td>
      <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row["abril"]; ?></td>
      <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row["mayo"]; ?></td>
      <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row["junio"]; ?></td>
      <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row["julio"]; ?></td>
      <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row["agosto"]; ?></td>
      <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row["septiembre"]; ?></td>
      <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row["octubre"]; ?></td>
      <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row["noviembre"]; ?></td>
      <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row["diciembre"]; ?></td>
      <td class="text-center"><?php echo "total"; ?></td>

 
    </tr>

    <?php } ?>
  </tbody>
```

y las tablas de donde traigo la informacion son tres:

Tabla atencurativasxesta:

[image: Tabla atencurativasxesta]

Tabla sibasis:

[image: Tabla sibasis]

Tabla establecimientos:

[image: Tabla establecimientos]

He estado intentando hacerlo pero no logro.

Muchas Gracias

Comment: que fue lo que intentaste? si vas recorriendo tu tabla, y vas controlando sibasi, siempre y cuando este ordenada por ese campo, que impide que cuando cambiaste de sibasi, imprimas la fila de totales? con los valores que fuiste acumulando hasta ahi?

Comment: Gracias por comentar @gbianchi, pues yo recorro la tabla atencurativasxesta y mediate un inner join le incorporo el a que sibasi correponde cada registro, lo que no se como hacer es el interumpir el recorrido y cuando cambie de sibasi (por ejemplo cuando cambio de sibasi centro a sibasi oriente) me genere una nueva fila y sume los valor de cada mes y asi tener el total por cada mes de todos los registros de un sibasi.